# Even there is value below first row V LOOKUP Returns 0

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two different excel sheets. In one excel sheet I have only "Part number" in another one I have Part number and Plant. I am trying to get the Plant details in first excel sheet. Below are the screen shot for your reference.

Primary
[image]

Secondary
[image]

Expected result
[image]

I know the first row is zero hence I am getting zero in all the rows. Is there a way, If the vlookup finds a matching value that has a blank cell associated with it, look down the list until you find that matching value that has something in the cell next to it?? I tried the below function without any success.

`=VLOOKUP(A2,IF(ISBLANK([Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!$BL:$BL),0,[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$BL,29,0)`

Any help in solving this issue will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following data from A1 in Sheet 1 and data for Material is grouped, but not necessarily sorted:

```
Material Part   
166 
166 
166 
166     XYZ
166 
166 
167 
167 
167     ABC
167 
167 
167 
167 
167
```

to get the following result in Sheet2 from A1:

```
Material    Part No.
167         ABC
166         XYZ
```

Formula in B2:

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)-2,1,COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A2)),MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)-2,1,COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A2))),0))
```

Note above is a array formula to be enter with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: Hello Nitesh Thanks a to for the response, I am not able apply this formula. I have two excel workbooks named "Primary" & "Secondary". In both the workbooks I have only one sheet named "Sheet1". In both the workbook Column A is "Material" . in the workbook named "secondary" under column AC I have plant details. Now I have to get the column AC details in the workbook Named "Primary". The material number is duplicated and not sorted. Please help in modifying the formula.

Comment: Different workbooks shouldn't be a factor as long as you are able to change the cell reference correctly. The material number should be GROUPED, not necessarily sorted (Edited answer). As long as it is grouped in the second workbook (as shown in your screenshot), it will work. However, Jeeped's solution works for both unsorted and ungrouped data.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$15)/((A$2:A$15=E2)*(B$2:B$15<>"")), 1))
'another workbook's columns A and AC
=INDEX([Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!AC:AC, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$15)/(([Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!A$2:A$15=a2)*([Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!AC$2:AC$15<>"")), 1))
```

Sample¹:

[image]

¹ <sub>Thanks to [Nitesh Halai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5752528/nitesh-halai) for supplying sample data that did not have to be retyped from an image.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and sorry I did not knew how to upload excel workbooks, hence posted screen shots. I am trying to do Vlookup between two excel workbook not in the same sheet. As shown in the above screen shot Column A & B in one excel workbook and only Column E  in another workbook, F is the result I am expecting. I am not able to apply the formula. Please help!